# Geocoder forceclose

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-geocoder

I have this application that is supposed to get the address from longitude and latitude but it keeps forceclosing when I push the button to call the information.

**Logcat Error:**

```
10-25 14:33:51.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11166):     at http.www.hotapp.com.timeandlocation.LocationManagerHelper.getAddress(LocationManagerHelper.java:51)
```

**My Geocoder Code**

```
public static boolean getAddress(){
  Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context);
  try {
    geoCoder.getFromLocation(getLatitude(), getLongitude(), 0);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return true;
}
```

The logcat error is saying that the error is on the line with `new Geocoder`. please help.

Comment: Can you post what the rest of the exception stack trace is? Also, where do you define your `context` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context that you are using is probably wrong, it should be that of the calling Activity.

Comment: So I am assuming you mean that `context` is wrong and instead I should be using something like `this` or `OtherActivity.class`. I tried changing 'context to the calling activity witch would be `OtherActivity.class` and I get an error saying `The constructor Geocoder(class<OtherActivity>) is undefined` I even changed it to `this` but got the same error. I also changed it to say `null` and got the same forceclose error. Do you have any idea what the problem   could be?

Comment: Also I changed it from `public static boolean` to `public static <List> Address getAddress(){`

Comment: Never mind, I had to stick the Geocoder into the right activity. Thanks for your help.